# How to change the css of testng reports?

Tags: java, c#, automated-tests, testng, extentreports

Is there a way to change the css/customize the html of TestNG Reports (not programmatically)?

I am using TestNG default reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be done programmatically. Create a sub-class of `EmailableReporter2` class. Override the `writeStylesheet` method as follows

```
protected void writeStylesheet() {
    writer.print("<link rel=\"stylesheet" href=\"/path/to/your/css/file.css\">");
}
```

or if u want to use internal css

```
protected void writeStylesheet() {
    writer.print("<style type=\"text/css\">");
    writer.print("your css");
    writer.println("</style>");
}
```

Use this sub-class as your TestNG listener class